# Limit at endpoints

Tags: calculus, limits, propositional-calculus

The definition of limit states (Spivak):

> **The function $f$ approaches the limit $l$ near $a$ means**: for every
>   $\varepsilon >0$ there is some $\delta >0$ such that, for all $x$, if
>   $0< |x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

and if its not true that $f$ approaches $l$ near $a$:

> There is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ there
>   is some $x$  which satisfies $0<|x-a|<\delta$ but not
>   $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

There are some textbooks that provide the definition of limit with the additional condition "for all $x \in D_{f}\dots$", but it seems to me that Spivak doesn't find it necessary.

So, supposing this condition is neither logically necessary nor implicit, suppose $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}g(x)=L$ for some function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$.  In order to verify that actually $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=L$, we could prove that the negated form of the limit definition above is false for $g$ near $a$. However, when $x<a$, $x$ is outside de domain of $g$, and $f(x)$ is not defined. So, perhaps, it's not the case that we have a vacuously true statement, because testing the veracity of an expression containing $|f(x)-L|$ does not even make logical sense at all.

What happens in a logical statement when a free variable takes a particular instance that turns an expression of it into nonsense? The statement should be ignored as a whole?

In the example above, when $x<a$, for any $\delta>0$ there are plenty of $x$ which satisfy $0<|x-a|<\delta$. But, is it true that  $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$?

By which logical means does the definition of limit given still applies when $g$ approaches $a$?

Comment: What is $D_f$??? A disk of some sorts? Interval? Are we doing this for real or complex $x$?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen the domain of $f$. Real

Comment: See Spivak's comment page 92: "In order for lim ... to be defioned, it is not necessary for $f$ to be defined at $a$, nor it is necessary for $f$ to be defined at all point $x \ne a$. However, there must be some $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x)$ is defined for $x$ satisfying $0 < |x-a| < \delta$; otherwise the clause "if ..." would make no sense at all, since the symbol $f(x)$ would make no sense for some $x$'s".

Comment: There is a "subtle" point here; the needed condition is neither "for all $x$" nor "for all $x \in D_f$". It must be something like: "$f$ approaches the limit $L$ as $x$ tends to $a$ along $E$" where $E$ is a subset of the domain of $f$; the condition now will be: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in E \cap [x-a, x+a]$ ...

Comment: You can see Serge Lang, [Undergraduate Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=e54cqeAmf4QC), page 41, or Terence Tao, [Analysis I](https://books.google.it/books?id=ecTsDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA220) (3rd ed, 2016), page 220 or Vladimir Zorich, [Mathematical Analysis I](https://books.google.it/books?id=rxOoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA106) (2nd ed, 2016), page 106.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Had I read a little further... I rather appreciate the other references provided

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things: As far as I know, the $x\in{D}_f$ is necessary. Spivak is being slightly sloppy, in that when he states for all $x$, he is assuming that $x$ is in the domain of $f$. Afterall, if not, as you note, $f(x)-L$ has no meaning to it. In fact, if you are being precise about it, the domain of a function is a implicitly carried forward. For example, if you consider the sine function on $[0,2\pi]$ and the sine function defined on the whole real line. They are both functions, but certainly are not the same function. (Think about the definition of a function in terms of a set of ordered pairs).

However is this inability to plugin numbers really a problem? To me this seems to be related to modus ponens in the following way: Consider the statement: if $l_1, l_2$ are two non-parallel lines, then they intersect. Now suppose that you plugin $0$ for $l_1$ and $1$ for $l_2$. Now the statement if $0, 1$ are two non-parallel lines, then they intersect is still true. But the problem is that you can't conclude that $0$ intersets $1$ as a result (i.e. $p$ implies $q$ is true, but in order to conclude $q$ you need $p$ to hold too). So in some sense the issue you raise "non-sensical" things being plugged in is always there, but it doesn't really cause any problems, because while you can plugin "garbage", they don't yield the things you want through modus ponens.

Comment: It seems to me that $f(x)$ isn't an antecedent in a conditional statement as the example you provided. I thought now of $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ as a statement about $x$, $f$, $L$, and $\varepsilon$, say $P(x,f,L,\varepsilon)\equiv\exists y[(x,y)\in f \land |y-L|<\varepsilon ]$. Thus, plugging in garbage for $x$ would turn the whole expression false by modus tollens repeatedly: $\forall \varepsilon[\varepsilon>0 \implies \exists \delta[\delta >0 \land \forall x(|x-a|<0\implies \exists y[(x,y)\in f \land |y-L|<\varepsilon])]]$.

Comment: @Fred: It isn't clear to me what you are stating. The point I was trying to make is the following:  * if and only if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=L$ where * is the definition of the limit, so everything that you have written, with P etc, is on the left. Now you can plug in all sorts of ''garbage in side *" but you can't conclude that the limit of $f$ is $L$ at $a$ based on the fact that it holds when $x$ is garbage. The point is that it needs to hold when $x$ is in the domain and satisfies being small enough.

Comment: I intended to say that, as you pointed, we cannot assign the symbol "$f(x)$" a meaning *per se*, without considering the domain of the function together. So it seemed reasonable to me that whenever we encounter a property $P$ involving $f(x)$, if nothing is stated about the domain of $f$, it is legitimate to replace $P(x)$by $\exists y((x,y)\in f \land P(y))$.

Comment: If $a$ is a endpoint, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ $\iff$ the definition of limit is satisfied $\iff$ we plug in $x$'s that are inside the domain, otherwise we will end up with $\exists y((x,y)\in f \land P(y))$ being false. So, it does matter whether we plug in garbage, because $p\to q$ is true no matter $p$ is true or not, but is false if $q$ is false, by *modus tollens*

Comment: @Fred: What you are stating is true! Plugin in a $x_0$ not in the domain. Then as you state, the statement with $x_0$ plugged in is true (i.e. $P(x_0,f,L,\epsilon_0)$ is true. But it still isn't enough to conclude the limit is $L$! As you have noted yourself, you still need to check all the other possibilities for $x$ including when $x$ is in the domain!

Comment: I noted some typos of mine above: "[...]  $\forall \varepsilon[\varepsilon>0 \implies \exists \delta[\delta >0 \land \forall x(|x-a|<\delta \implies \exists y[(x,y)\in f \land |y-L|<\varepsilon])]]$ [...]" and "[...] to replace $P(f(x))$". Anyway, I thought of $P(x_0,f,L,\varepsilon_0)$ being false with $x_0$ outside the domain. Provided the other conditions are met, e.g., $|x_0-a|<\delta$ etc, I see $P(x_0,f,L,\varepsilon_0)$ as decisive to conclude $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

Comment: @Fred: It is not enough, What you claiming is akin to saying: one flower is red, therefore all flowers are red.

Comment: @Fred The problem is the way you are handling the quantifiers. Say $x_0$ is s.t. $0<a-x_0<\delta$. Now $\exists{y}....$  is false, so that $0<a-x_0<\delta \implies \exists{y}....$ is true. But now, you want to conclude $\forall x ({0<|x-a|<\delta \implies \exists{y}}....)$ is true. But you can't do this! It is the same fallacy as concluding all flowers are red because one flower is red.

Comment: I want to conclude $\forall x ({0<|x-a|<\delta \implies \exists{y}}....)$ is false (when using $x$ outside the domain). As I said, because if $p$ is true and $q$ is false $p\to q$ is false.

Comment: @Fred You can't conclude that. If $x_0$ is outside the domain, then $p(x_0,f,L,\epsilon_0)$ will be true, it will not be false. This keeps with our intuitive understanding that in order for the limit to not exist, there should be values of $x$ in the domain for which the relevant conditions fail regardless of how close we get to $a$.

Comment: The only way to show that $\forall(x).....$ fails, is to find an $x_0\in{D_f}$ that causes it to fail.